# Can't delete hive box in flutter web

Tags: flutter, flutter-hive

The `await` statement is never resolved and the fluter web app hangs at this line:

```
await Hive.deleteBoxFromDisk('stop_user')
```

Any soluntions?

Comment: Have you tried to specify the path? Do you get any error messages? You can add a timeout to every Future, so that the app will not hang there forever.